# `\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn` seems to discard original token values (but iterate the right number of tokens)

Tags: expl3

From https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf :
`\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn {⟨token list⟩} {⟨inline function⟩}`
`Applies the ⟨inline function⟩ to each individual ⟨token⟩ in the ⟨token list⟩. The ⟨inline function⟩ receives three arguments as explained above.`

The 3 arguments are `<token>`, `<char code>`, `<catcode>`.

When using `\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn`, it seems to iterate the correct number of times (# of input tokens in first arg), but their token value doesn't seem to be forwarded properly to the `inline function`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myprependWithX}{mO{}O{}}
 {
  X#1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myprependWithX{a} % Expect Xa (and get it)

\myprependWithX{a}{}{} % Expect Xa (and get it)

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn{ x y z }{ \myprependWithX } % Expect XxXyXz (but get XXX)
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Why don't we get `XxXyXz` from `\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn` here?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a function with optional arguments as optional arguments must be given in brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood the "inline function". The functions in `expl3` that have `inline` in their name expect that you provide code in their last argument as you'd do for a `\cs_set:Nn`. So you need to access the values with parameters as `#1`, `#2`, and `#3` (in the case of `\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn`).

Also your understanding of the optional arguments defined with `O` is wrong, they expect an argument in `[]`, not an optional argument in `{}`. To show that they don't do what you expect I changed the replacement text to `X#3#2#1` so you'll see that your usage doesn't work out.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myprependWithX}{mO{}O{}}
 {
  X#3#2#1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myprependWithX{a}{b}{c} % wrong usage
\myprependWithX{a}[b][c] % right usage


\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn{ x y z }{ X#1 } ~ % Expect XxXyXz
\tl_analysis_map_inline:nn { x y z } { \myprependWithX{#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```